# centering an image in a compoundTextView, moves the text down

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, imageview

I have an image with size 6x10 dp

I want to add it dynamically to a textView.

I have 3 text view and according to some state I add it as a compoundDrawable.

```
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(targetTextView, null, null, drawable, null);
```

I want the image to be almost centered vertically to the text view + 1 sp length lower than the center. So in each text view I added

```
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

so:

I have tried to

1) create a canvas with height 8 x 10 and center it to the text view and then the drawers bound to (0,1sp, 10, 8-1sp)

but it seems the text view moved downwards as well relative to its position before adding the compund imageView.

[image]

2) create a canvas with heightof the textview and center it to the text view and then the drawers bound to (0,(textView height - 6) /2, 10, ...)

[image]

but then waiting for the observerTree make the code combersome.

Any other way to do this?

here is my code for the (1) option:

```
  private void tintAndAddPadding(

...


      @DrawableRes int drawableId, @ColorRes int colorId) {
    Drawable drawable =
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableId));
    Drawable drawableWithTint = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(
        drawableWithTint.mutate(), getContext().getResources().getColor(colorId));
    // Bitmap dimensions sets the canvas dimensions
    Bitmap bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(
            getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_width),
            getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_canvas_height),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // Drawable bounds should be all 4 coordinates on the canvas to draw on.
    // This implies the drawable width and height.
    drawableWithTint.setBounds(
        0,
        getContext()
            .getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_top_padding)
        , canvas.getWidth(),
        canvas.getHeight() -
            getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_top_padding));
    drawableWithTint.draw(canvas);

   TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(targetTextView, null, null, drawableWithTint, null);
    // Padding between text and drawable
    targetTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
        getContext()
            .getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_left_padding))
  }
```

- I know i can use relativeLayout, but my team encourages me to use compoundText nevertheless.

Comment: From my basic understanding of what you are trying to do, is it impossible to use a RelativeLayout and position the TextView and ImageView behind it?

Comment: @karthikprasad it's possible. but it's a small bug fix. i prefer not changing current hierarchy. is it possible?

Comment: Try this - https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/android-gotchas-1-setting-a-drawable-on-a-textview-programatically-9e7a10e1562a